# ANDROID_HOME and PATH error when debugging an android app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, path, environment-variables

[image: MY ERROR] I already added Tools and Platform-Tools directories to the path and set android_home to the original android directory but when I write the command line "ionic cordova run android " it threw an error. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Make sure you have `local.properties` file inside your project dir.

Comment: what do i need to do to add it ??

Comment: path to your `sdk`. Example https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/local.properties.example

Comment: Once try opening project in Android Studio, and run through its UI

Comment: i don't use it i only use cmd

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to add two paths for run ionic app in real device.
`ANDR0ID_HOME` and `GRADLE_HOME`, and for that you need to open your environment file that is in etc folder, or try this command

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/environment
```

after fire this command, gedit is open,
set your ANDROID_HOME path like,

ANDROID_HOME="/home/android/Sdk/"

and same like this you need to set GRADLE_HOME path or you also paste it into the PATH variable.

In GRADLE_HOME variable you need to provide the gradle path from the android-studio folder

save it and logged out
after logged in your path is set.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't set the path of android sdk.

For Windows : (Set path like)

```
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\ installation location \android-sdk
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
```

For Ubuntu :

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
```

I hope this would be helpful

Source : http://spring.io/guides/gs/android/

Answer (score 0):

From the Android web site, download the correct version of the Android SDK for your operating system.

Unzip the archive to a location of your choosing. For example, on Linux or Mac, you can place it in the root of your user directory. See the Android Developers web site for additional installation details.

Configure the ANDROID_HOME environment variable based on the location of the Android SDK. Additionally, consider adding ANDROID_HOME/tools, and ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools to your PATH.